# How to grab 'Australia' from the tag '<th>Australia</th>'

Tags: python

I'm trying to grab Australia from this tag

```
<tr>
<td>City</td>
<th>Sydney</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Country</td>
<th>Australia</th>
</tr>

import re
from re import findall
a = '<tr>\n<td>Country</td>\n<th>Australia</th>\n</tr>'
country = re.findall(r'<tr><td>Country</td><th>(.*?)</th></tr>',a)
print country

result: []
```

This is an html code, i tried to use import re and from re import findall to grab the Australia

I expect the result:Australia, but it gave me result:[]

I wish not to use beautifulsoup. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you would choose regex over bs4 in this instance. For future readers this is doable with bs4 4.7.1. you can use `:contains` pseudo class along with adjacent sibling combinator to get `th` next to `td` containing "Country"

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<tr>
<td>City</td>
<th>Sydney</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Country</td>
<th>Australia</th>
</tr>
'''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml') # 'html.parser' if lxml not installed  
countries =  soup.select('td:contains(Country) + th')
if countries: print(countries[0].text)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have just missed the newline (\n) characters in your regular expression:

```
pattern = '<tr>\\n<td>Country</td>\\n<th>(.*?)</th>\\n</tr>'
```

Here is the tested [regex](https://regex101.com/r/Dw2oV6/1)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) like this to only look for `th` tags specifally:

```
>>> import re
>>> html = '<tr>\n<td>Country</td>\n<th>Australia</th>\n</tr>'
>>> country = re.findall(r'<th>(.*?)</th>', html)[0]
>>> country
Australia
```

If you don't want to use [BeautfulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) (shown below) for some reason.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> a = '<tr>\n<td>Country</td>\n<th>Australia</th>\n</tr>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(a, 'html.parser')
>>> country = soup.find('th').text
>>> country
Australia
```